# Sharing Mercurial repository between desktop and laptop using TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

We use BitBucket for managing our source code. There is a small team of developers with access to the repository.  I sometimes have changes that I am happy to commit to my local repository I don't yet want to share with the other developers, but would like to be able to share between my two dev machines. Is there an easy and safe way to synchronize the repositories on the two machines without pushing up to BitBucket.

It seems like there is, given the nature of distributed version control. I suspect that this is an obvious answer to many; I am still moving my mindset over from the SVN world.

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options I use:

- Make a private repository on your bitbucket account and use that, too.
- Use a flash stick or external hard drive.

You could also share a directory or use [`hg serve`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/hgserve) to link directly between the two computers while they are on the same network. I do the above two because one machine is at home and the other at work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You push directly to that repository. In TortoiseHG, you click the down-arrow beside the textbox (that normally points to your Bitbucket repo) and change it to "local". Then you type in the path to that repo (the base repo directory, not the ".hg" directory). And then you push to it. Or pull from it. You can even save them with names for easier access (use the save button to the right of the repo text box).